# Python regular expression to exclude the end with string

Tags: python, regex, string

i have a file with rows like

```
From david.horwitz@uct.ac.za Fri Jan  4 06:08:27 2008
Received: (from apache@localhost)
Return-Path: <postmaster@collab.sakaiproject.org>
for <source@collab.sakaiproject.org>;
```

I was trying to read each line and use regular expression to find the domain name, basically the portion after the sign @. Here is the code I wrote

```
if re.search('[@]\S+?', line) : org = re.findall('@(\S+)',line)[0]
```

But it returns the following results

```
uct.ac.za
localhost)
collab.sakaiproject.org>
collab.sakaiproject.org>;
```

Is there any smart way to only keep the domain and do not include the ')', '>' or '>;'  followed by the domain name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slight correction - a FQDN can include numbers also...

so the regex needs a slight adjustment to

[@][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+

Full Domain rules at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator

Answer (score 2):

Try this

use regex negation for to do it, `[^\>\)\s]+`

```
if re.search('@([^\>\)\s]+)', line) : org = re.findall('@([^\>\)\s]+)',line)[0]
```

output

```
uct.ac.za
localhost
collab.sakaiproject.org
collab.sakaiproject.org
```